How to mention a follower using the LinkedIn API?
I have tried many endpoints but have constantly encountered problems. (I must say that I really struggle navigating LinkedIn's documentation...).
My objective is as follows: to create a profile search feature (follower of my page or my 1st-degree connections) to retrieve their "URN" so I can mention them in my posts.
The latest avenues I have explored are:

Using the "/connections" endpoint to navigate within my network. The problem is I do not have the necessary permissions, and "r_network" no longer seems operational.

Using the "/peopleTypeahead" endpoint to search by keyword. I have the impression that this is the key to my problems, but I cannot get my function to work properly. Indeed, I do not know if I should use in the query: organizationFollowers or memberConnections. In any case, the elements array is empty.


public function searchByKeywordForOrganizationPage(SocialNetworkPage $page, string $keywords) {
    $list = [];
    $url = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/peopleTypeahead?";
    $queryParam = [
         //'q' => 'organizationFollowers',
        'q' => 'memberConnections',
         //'organization' => $page->getPageId(),
        'keywords' => 'Leo'
    ];
    $url .= http_build_query($queryParam, encoding_type: PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
    $result = $this->httpClient->request('GET', $url, [
        'headers' => [
            'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0',
            'LinkedIn-Version' => 202405,
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $page->getAccessToken(),
        ],
    ]);

    return $result;

}

I have the impression that only the administrators of the page can be tagged, and now I am going in circles.
The only thing that works is to use 'vanityUrl' endpoint but this does not allow me to search by keyword.
Has anyone gone through this before?

Still no solution at the moment. I guess I will forfeit

Here is a response from a Linkedin's Developer...
if the profile is not EN_US it is expected not to be returned. I also added some other main reasons profiles may not be returned.
peopleTypeAhead API will only return profiles with settings that match the following:
Profile visibility
3rd party data sharing
Mentions setting
M2M block on viewer
Missing first name and last name and headline
Match only on maiden name or additional name but these names not set to public
https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a541878/creating-or-deleting-a-profile-in-another-language
In other words they may be hidden or not visible in their respective settings. Double check those settings and let me know if you still run into issues.
